# How can i make this simple for loop run every second?

Tags: c#, for-loop, console

it is a simple timer that starts from a value set by user and counts down to 0

```
namespace SuperSimpleTimer
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This makes the loop starts from a user inserted value
           myTime = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = myTime; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // clears the old value and Writes the new one
                //Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(i);

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);` for a delay of 1 second - but i assume that's not what you really want to happen

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Time delay in For loop in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9946782/time-delay-in-for-loop-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The Simplest way would be:

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);
```

This should be applied like this:

```
using System.Threading;

namespace SuperSimpleTimer
{
    class Program
    {


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //This makes the loop starts from a user inserted value
           myTime = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

            for (int i = myTime; i >= 0; i--)
            {
                // clears the old value and Writes the new one
                //Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine(i);
                Thread.Sleep(1000); //1000(ms) = 1 second

            }
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also add some input validation/checking (non integers with `int.TryParse`, negative values) to improve OP code

Comment: It's good to keep in mind that the simplest solution is not always the best solution.